# How to log multiple errors in TRY..CATCH?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My application runs SQL scripts to load in data and when there's a problem with the file it's loading, it only logs the last error which doesn't contain the useful information about why the file won't load.

Example code:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BULK INSERT MyTableName
    FROM 'C:\MyFilename.txt'
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    TABLOCK, 
    MAXERRORS=0,
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\MyFilename_Errors.log'
    )
    ;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    INSERT INTO MyErrorLog
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() as Issue
    , ERROR_LINE() as IssueRowNum
    ;
END CATCH
```

This script will create an entry in [MyErrorLog] for the third error (see below). And the log file will tell me what line, but not what field:

> Row 30539 File Offset 1910820 ErrorFile Offset 0 - HRESULT 0x80004005

Here's all 3 lines if I "THROW" the error inside the CATCH:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for
>   row 1, column 5 (MyField).
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The OLE DB provider "BULK" for
>   linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give
>   any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 3 Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB
>   provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

How do I capture that first (and second) error message?

Comment: Try Catch only gets the last message i'm almost positive.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem.  I also need the first error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only capture a single error in a T-SQL CATCH block. According to [this connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/746979/try-catch-construct-catches-last-error-only), the workaround is to use `THROW` (or not use TRY/CATCH) and capture the errors in client code.

Consequently, you'll need to invoke the script from a client application (including SQLCLR) so that you can capture and log all errors.

Comment: Using a THROW only displays it as if I had not done a TRY/CATCH as you say.  My script is loading multiple files and I wouldn't have a way of tying errors caught in code to the the correct file.  So the real answer is I can't do it I guess.

Comment: @VenerableAgents, correct, what you want can only be done in client code (including SQLCLR). I'll update my answer to make that clearer.